# Cannot get <a> elements to navbar height

Tags: html, css

I have this navbar where the listed items do not span the complete height of the navbar. Most of the posts I have seen have talked about padding and margin, but none of what I have should effect what is going on. Any tips would be great, thanks.

```css
#navbar {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-end;
   width: 100%;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   padding: 0;
   position: fixed;
   background-color: slategray;
}

#nav-list {
   display: flex;
   margin-right: 5rem;
   list-style: none;
}

#nav-list a {
   display: block;
   padding: 1rem;
   color: white;
   font-size: 1.5rem;
   text-decoration: none;
   border: 1px solid black;
}

#nav-list a:hover {
   background: grey;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
   <ul id="nav-list">
      <li><a>item1</a></li>
      <li><a>item2</a></li>
      <li><a>item3</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

EDIT: Thank you all for the fast answer, the margin was the problem and I swear I played with that and it changed nothing. I appreciate all the possible solutions that resolved this and teaching me the default behavior of ul margins!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the `margin-right` rule in the `#nav-list` ruleset with a complete margin rule: `margin: 0 5rem 0 0;`. This will reset the browser's default styling and make it work as you wanted.

```css
#navbar {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-end;
   width: 100%;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   padding: 0;
   position: fixed;
   background-color: slategray;
}

#nav-list {
   display: flex;
   /*margin-right: 5rem; instead of this*/
   margin: 0 5rem 0 0; /*use this*/
   list-style: none;
}

#nav-list a {
   display: block;
   padding: 1rem;
   color: white;
   font-size: 1.5rem;
   text-decoration: none;
   border: 1px solid black;
}

#nav-list a:hover {
   background: grey;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
   <ul id="nav-list">
      <li><a>item1</a></li>
      <li><a>item2</a></li>
      <li><a>item3</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ul` by default has `margin-block-start: 1em` and `margin-block-end: 1em`.

To fix this add `margin: 0` to `#nav-list`.

```css
#nav-list { 
  display:flex; 
  margin:0; 
  margin-right: 5rem; 
  list-style: none 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Now this will work...

```css
#navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: slategray;
}

#nav-list {
  margin: 0;          /*added*/
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 5rem;
  list-style: none;
}

#nav-list a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#nav-list a:hover {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <ul id="nav-list">
    <li><a>item1</a></li>
    <li><a>item2</a></li>
    <li><a>item3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only concerned with height, just remove margin-top and margin-bottom from #nav-list.

Try this:

```
#nav-list {
   display: flex;
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0 80px 0 16px;
}
```